# How to get database schema from previously backed up but not known file of SQL-Server in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

I got an old project of ASP.net Web Form [Solution Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNvPl.png) where only a file exists under database folder which is related to database, no .mdf files.

I have tried import, restore database, attach all ways to get the Database Schema from SSMS, nothing worked. Got error
[While Attaching as .mdf File in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WMyw.png).
Maybe, I had used 2008 sql server and now from sql server 2017, is that a problem or other things?

Is there a possible ways to get database structure from that file?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file with a text editor? What does it contain?

Comment: You said `no .mdf files` but in your second image, it shows `E:\ARS.mdf is not a primary database file ....` ? How do you attach the `mdf` ? How about `ldf` ? Did you include it together during the attach process ?

Answer (score 0):

There confusion in your question (2nd line), do you mean `.ldf`?, if so, try following:

1. Create a dummy database with same name
2. Run following query

It detach existing files of newly created database (Dummy Database) and attach new file that you desired to:

```
EXEC sp_detach_db @dbname = 'DatabaseName';  
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'DatabaseName',   
    @physname =   
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewDBFile.mdf';
```

Comment: In the first screnshot, the ARS file has no extension... so I don't think it's a SQL Server file.  First thing I'd do is look at the config files for a connection string. That should give a clue as to what type of database you're dealing with.